# how get the value of a script tag

Tags: ruby, watir

In my page code, there is this script tag:

```
<script>
  var oid = "182384";
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = oGrid;
  oGrid.setShowSid(false);
  oGrid.calcSize();
  setupAllTabs();
  var toolbar = setupMenuButtons("btnbar");

  initForm(toolbar);
</script>
```

How can I get the value of oid with watir or ruby?

Comment: Have you tried anything? How bout getting the script tag then use a simple regex?

Answer (score 5):

`browser.script.html` will output the code within the `<script>` tag.  For example:

```
require 'watir'  

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto("http://www.some_site_with_script.com")
browser.script.html
```

Then--as @rainkinz indicates--you can extract whatever values you want using regex:

```
b.script.html.match(/var\soid\s\=\s\"\d+\"/)
```

Comment: Thank @orde and don't forget to mark his answer correct as that looks pretty good to me.